# Returning an element of a list in python 3 returns None

Tags: python-3.x, return-value

I have been trying to understand how scope of variables work in python 3 along with the concept of mutability of objects. This is confusing me because Code 1 returns None (even after printing the correct value in the line before) but code 2 returns the correct value

**Code1**

```
def quick_select(numbers,p,r,i):
    if p == r:
        return numbers[p]
    q = partition(numbers,p,r)
    if i == q:
        print(numbers[q]) # prints the correct Value
        return numbers[q] # returns None
    if i < q:
        quick_select(numbers,p,q-1,i)
    else:
        quick_select(numbers,q+1,r,i)
```

**Code 2**

```
def foo(a):
    if a[0] > 15:
        return a[0]/15
    else:
        return a[0]

x = [120,30]
print(foo(x)) # works perfectly fine
```

Comment: You do understand that you have code paths that don't return anything, right?

Comment: your `quick_select` function calls itself but discards the value and returns nothing at the top level. The None is not coming fron where you think its coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being confused by the recursion. Here is your **Code1** block, with comments adjusted to reflect what is actually going on:

```
def quick_select(numbers,p,r,i):
    if p == r:
        return numbers[p]
    q = partition(numbers,p,r)
    if i == q:
        print(numbers[q]) # prints the correct Value
        return numbers[q] # returns the correct value
    if i < q:
        quick_select(numbers,p,q-1,i) # discards the returned value
    else:
        quick_select(numbers,q+1,r,i) # discards the returned value

    # getting to the end of a function without hitting a return is the same as
    # return None
```

Comment: Thanks guys, gotta be more careful with recursion next time.